# Jquery: prepend content retrieved with .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm loading an svg through ajax with jquery like so:

```
$("body").load("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg");
```

Which loads just fine, but replaces all the content in the body. What I want it to do is prepend the loaded svg, so the svg does not replace everything but is inserted as the first element after `<body>`.

Comment: replace body with $("#svg") ?

Comment: By the way; I checked the .prepend method, but couldn't get it to work with .load, I'm pretty new to this..

Comment: I don't see why you would need a prepend method at all. You load the content inside the element you provide. If you use body your body will be overwritten. If you use an empty div like #svg the svg will be loaded before the rest of the content.

Comment: @gulty; That's true, but I need to insert it without wrapping it into an extra element (or providing an empty element in the html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    $("body").prepend(data);
  }
})
```

You have to adjust the datatype in case you want to get different content (e.g. xml/json elements).

Works with your example - svg is right below the body and before your #svg div.

Answer (score 1):

Use $.get() then do prepend in the callback:

```
$.get( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg" )
  .done(function( data ) {
      $("body").prepend($(data).find("svg"));
  });
```

Comment: Aparently it was being parsed as xml instead of html should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot just place an image retrieved into body like so.
If you want to display image, just show it via img tag.
If you retrieve data, you can use something like this:

```
$.get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg" )
  .success(function(data) {
      $("body").prepend(data.activeElement.innerHTML);
  });
```

The reason why your initial variant "worked" by showing an entire picture is that browsers can display image files, and your code just did that - the same would be if you just drag-n-drop an image into browser window.

Comment: You're right, but I want to insert the raw data (I'm doing a variant of this: http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/). So I don't want to display it as an image, but just insert the contents raw into the html (the wikimedia svg is just for testing purposes).

Comment: oh, I see, then use the 'data' variable inside 'success' to display your data retrieved, and use prepend/append based on your purposes.

Comment: See my edit. It actualy loads (you can see it via inspector), but due to that it have a lot of markup, it will not show completely. But you can output it into console to see that it actualy loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code I checked it and working fine.

```
$("#svg").load("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg");
```

Comment: It works, but it wraps the inserted content in a div (with an id of svg), which I want to avoid.